# Add PHP to apache on mac os?

Tags: apache, php-7

I tried to upgrade php 5.6 to php 7, but I caused there a error with trying of this method: `https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/` now I uninstalled this and tried to install php 7 over *brew*, it works but is still not added to apache, in browser I see still only pure php code.

I tried also to add this line to httpd.conf but no changes:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

the path is correct, knows someone how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add the following declaration to httpd.conf for Apache to parse PHP files via php7_module:

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Restarting of Apache may also be required for the new settings to take effect.

Comment: thx! Both two snippets fixed the problem for me. But WTF .. - Why have these lines been missing in brew's httpd.conf `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` after installing apache and php72 ? :(